# wxPython how to move items to new row if they become hidden?

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, wxpython

I have a collection of buttons arranged in a row.
Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)

panel = wx.Panel(frame, wx.ID_ANY)
box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

for i in range(10):
    btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Test")
    box.Add(btn, 1, wx.FIXED_MINSIZE)
    
panel.SetSizer(box)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Making the window smaller leads to the buttons being hidden, as would be expected. However, I want the buttons to retain their dimensions and be moved to a second row instead of shrinking and finally disappearing. I have tried using different settings and different types of sizers but with no avail. How can I go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that wxPython has a sizer that does this. For some reason I didn't notice it on the docs before. For anyone stumbling on this in the future, you'll want to use `wx.WrapSizer` instead of `wx.BoxSizer`.

Comment: You live and learn. I've never come across it.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony : wxGlade does support it.... But I just found, I have never added it to the documentation....

See here for the wxPython documentation https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.WrapSizer.html